# Nginx ingress controller authentication not working

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, basic-authentication, nginx-ingress

I am running a gke cluster (v1.16.15gke.4300) and the nginx ingress authentication is failing. The below snippet is for external oauth2 authentication but even a basic auth is also not working. Seems that nginx is completely ignore these annotations.

The oauth2 proxy with google api **is actually working fine**, but nginx is not including the auth configuration on his own configuration. I can easily check that on the nginx running pods. No auth conf there.

nginx ingress controller:

```
  repoURL: 'https://helm.nginx.com/stable'
  targetRevision: 0.6.1
  version: nginx/1.19.2
```

The live manifest for an ingress service protected by oauth2:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: https://oauth2.####.net/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri
    ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://oauth2.####.net/oauth2/auth
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":##########}
  creationTimestamp: "####"
  finalizers:
  - networking.gke.io/ingress-finalizer-V2
  generation: 1
  labels:
    argocd.argoproj.io/instance: k8s-default
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  resourceVersion: "22174124"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/ingresses/dashboard-ingress
  uid: 34263f6b-6818-403f-####-4c6acb196c49
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.###.net
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: kdashboard-kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dashboard.###.net
    secretName: reflect-certificate-secret-internal
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: ##.##.##.##
```

When running the service i never get a 403/401:

```
curl -I 'https://dashboard.###.net/'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.19.2
Date: Mon, 14 Dec 2020 19:50:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1272
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: no-store
Last-Modified: Mon, 22 Jun 2020 14:25:00 GMT
```

Comment: Some people mentioned to use nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io instead of ingress.kubernetes.io but its the same.

Comment: Could you please try to add the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` annotation to your Ingress and share the results?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor nothing changes but I can have nginx action in some annotations like nginx.org/server-snippets , the others annotations don't trigger anything

Comment: `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` forces `Nginx Ingress` on GKE instead of the built-in GCP Ingress solution. Use that with the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io` annotations you mentioned in your first comment and please let me know about the outcome. I am analyzing your issue further in the meantime.

Comment: No, not yet. Moved on. but need to return to the problem. The ingress.class annotation doesn't change anything in my configuration.

Comment: Yes, I've tried multiple times with the default ingress class. or ingress.class" "nginx" the result is the same. the ingress works (via the right nginx) but auth the annotations seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Based on the info you provided it looks like that you are using the [Nginxinc Ingress Controller](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress#nginx-ingress-controller) and not the [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx#nginx-ingress-controller) which are not the same. Nginxinc Ingress Controller is different from the NGINX Ingress controller in [kubernetes/ingress-nginx repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx#nginx-ingress-controller) and also different from the default [GKE Ingress Controller](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress). The main difference that would affect your use case is that they all use different annotations and those annotations can only be satisfied by a proper Controller. You can find the key differences between the mentioned above [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/nginx-ingress-controllers.md) and [here](https://medium.com/omnius/kubernetes-ingress-gce-vs-nginx-controllers-1-3-d89d6dd3da73).

Below are some useful docs/guides:

- [External OAUTH Authentication](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/oauth-external-auth/#external-oauth-authentication): The `auth-url` and `auth-signin` annotations allow you to use an external authentication provider to protect your Ingress resources.
- [Securing your website with OAuth2 using NGINX Ingress Controller](https://toolbox.kurio.co.id/securing-your-website-with-oauth2-in-nginx-ingress-controller-c84984eae7fa): NGINX Ingress Controller can be combined with `oauth2_proxy` to enable many OAuth providers like Google, GitHub and others.
- [How to configure external OAuth authentication?](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/982)

To sum up:

- Choose the proper controller that would satisfy the annotations that you want to use.
- Keep in mind that different Controllers might use different annotations ([nginxinc](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/) vs [nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/)).
- Use `kubernetes.io/ingress.class:` annotation to choose the controller installed on your GKE Cluster.

Comment: I am using the helm repo:
NAME          URL
nginx-stable  https://helm.nginx.com/stable

Comment: the controller version from the kubernetes/ingress-nginx repo works fine. thanks for pointing it out.