# GKE Nginx Ingress Controller Oauth2 Proxy redirect

Tags: nginx, oauth-2.0, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to add authentication to my cluster by using an oauth2-proxy. Locally I tested and is working as expected: When I go to the landing page it redirects me to an IP such as GitHub. After login, I am redirected to my page and everything is working as expected. For some odd reason, when porting from local to the cluster living in the google cloud, I am not getting redirect to GitHub for authentication.
I have two ingresses, one for the oauth2-proxy (ingress-oauth2-proxy) and another for all of the apps (ingress-apps). I added the Nginx annotations and still nothing.

Here are the Ingress YAML file used for the creation of the ingress rules

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://auth.example.com/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://auth.exmaple.com/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-isuer: letsecnrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: $/1
  name: ingress-apps
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: echo.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: echo1
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - echo.exmaple.com
      secretName: echo-tls-cert
---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-oauth2-proxy
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: auth.exmaple.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: oauth2-proxy
          servicePort: 4180
        path: /oauth2
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - auth.exmaple.com
      secretName: auth-tls-cert
```

I checked the logs of the OAuth proxy and when I go to echo.example.com nothing happens. If I make a request to auth.example.com/oauth2 I get redirected, as expected, to the IP login page which is GitHub in this case.

Am I missing something?

Note: I checked and both ingresses are being applied.

Comment: Can you share the source of the page and the JavaScript console logs of the OAuth page where "nothing happens"?

Comment: Hello! Which one of the pages? I am sorry but I didn't t quite get your request. Let me just add that the landing page is just an echo HTTP server based on the hashicorp image and the proxy is based on the oauth2-proxy image of quay.io.  Please note that I am really new with anything related to web dev :/

Comment: Ok, I figured it out: The problem is the Ingress controller that I was using. I installed the Nginx controller from the repo helm.nginx.com/stable which is nginxinc and does not support the annotations. Therefore they were being ignored. To fix it I just used the kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#gce-gke. This is better explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65295598/nginx-ingress-controller-authentication-not-working . Cheers ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out: The problem was the Ingress controller used. I installed the Nginx controller from the repo helm.nginx.com/stable which is nginxinc and does not support the annotations. Therefore they were being ignored. To fix it I just used the kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#gce-gke. This is better explained here [Nginx ingress controller authentication not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65295598/nginx-ingress-controller-authentication-not-working)

Cheers ! :)